# how to transfer data from richtextbox to another richtextbox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

hi i have a problem in displaying or transfering the data in my richtextbox to other richtextbox...

```
richtextbox1.Document = richtextbox2.Document; //This will be the idea..
```

actually what i'm planning to do is, i want to transfer my data from my database to my listview which will display as what it is

```
SQLDataEHRemarks = myData["remarks"].ToString();// Here is my field from my database which is set as Memo
RichTextBox NewRichtextBox = new RichTextBox();// Now i created a new Richtextbox for me to take the data from SQLDataEHRemarks...
NewRichtextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();// Clearing
TextRange tr2 = new TextRange(NewRichtextBox.Document.ContentStart, NewRichtextBox.Document.ContentEnd);// I found this code from other forum and helps me a lot by loading data from the database....
MemoryStream ms2 = GetMemoryStreamFromString(SQLDataEHRemarks);//This will Convert to String
tr2.Load(ms2, DataFormats.Rtf);//then Load the Data to my NewRichtextbox
```

Now what i want to do is, im going to load this data to my ListView.. or other control like textblock or textbox...

```
_EmpHistoryDataCollection.Add(new EmployeeHistoryObject{
EHTrackNum = tr2.ToString()  // The problem here is it will display only the first line of the paragraph.. not the whole paragraph
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Text` property of the `TextRange` instead of `.ToString()`

Method to get the content of a `RichTextBox` as string:

```
public static string GetStringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

Method to get the content of a `RichTextBox` as rich text:

```
public static string GetRtfStringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    textRange.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);

    return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

**Edit:** You can put the rich text returned from GetRtfStringFromRichTextBox() in another `RichText` control by doing the following:

```
FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(richTextString));
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
textRange.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
richTextBox.Document = fd;
```

Comment: thank u so much... :) by the way how bout the data from listview or textbox send to richtextbox? sory for this...

Comment: @KenshiHemura check the last bit of my answer for one way to set the content of a RichTextBox.

Comment: Wouldn't getting the contents of a RichTextBox as string simply be something like:
(in VB.Net)
                            Dim strText as string = MyRTB.text

Comment: Late reply, but a more optimal way of getting the string out of it would be to use "StreamReader", which saves you making a whole array and *then* a new string object

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't getting the contents of a RichTextBox as string simply be something like
the following (in VB.Net)

```
Dim strText as string = MyRTB.text
```